# android kernel module failure

Tags: android, module, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

`insmod` of a cross compiled with `arm-linux-androideabi-` tools empty kernel module fails with:

```
[10076.773188] c1 Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 0000000c
[10076.773413] c1 pgd = e0de8000
[10076.773675] c1 [0000000c] *pgd=00000000
[10076.774155] c1 Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
[10076.774345] c1 Modules linked in: hello_4(+) dhd tntfs(P)
[10076.775159] c1 CPU: 1    Tainted: P              (3.4.5-1572434 #1)
[10076.775365] c1 PC is at sys_init_module+0x15dc/0x1d34
[10076.775644] c1 LR is at mutex_lock+0x20/0x90
...
[10076.865997] c1 Backtrace: 
[10076.866315] c1 [<c007d35c>] (sys_init_module+0x0/0x1d34) from 
[<c000ed40>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
[10076.866623] c1 Code: e15c0003 e2433008 0a00000a e1a06003 (e5963014) 
[10076.867140] c1 Board Information: SPC HW revision: 10, CPU EXYNOS5250 Rev1.0
[10076.867588] c1 ---[ end trace 6d11e1d2026a5e8c ]---
[10076.868028] c1 Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
[10076.868265] c0 CPU0: stopping
```

Code of the module:

```
static int __init init_hello_4(void)
{
    return 0;
}
static void __exit cleanup_hello_4(void)
{
}
module_init(init_hello_4);
module_exit(cleanup_hello_4);
```

At the same time "Hello World" program works. What could be a reason?

Comment: Show how do you build your kernel module.

Comment: It can't be a code of the module. It lacks mandatory headers.